# Creating a Script that will create user accounts (using useradd) from a .txt file of usernames

Tags: linux, bash

I need to create a script that will create user accounts (using useradd) from a .txt file of usernames. Please help me because my professor has not been the best of help.

The text file's name is users.txt

The only in the file is usernames, we are suppose to set up a default password and have it where they must change it on the next logon. We are also supposed to add them into a group called interns.

Here is what I have so far:

```
  #!/bin/bash

  for i in users.txt
  do
  sudo echo $i
  sudo useradd $i -m -d /home/$i -s /bin/bash $i -G sudo interns $i
  passwd = echo "AIST2330password" | passwd -stdin $i
  sudo passwd -e $i
  echo "User must change password when they come back"

  done
```

Comment: "Please help me because my professor has not been the best of help." is this homework?

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: It is practice from what we have read. Unfortunately, the chapters that the professor had us read does not really offer help with this.

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
for i in users.txt
```

should be:

```
for i in $(cat users.txt)
```

Your code is iterating over the literal string `users.txt`, not the contents of the file.

And this line:

```
passwd = echo "AIST2330password" | passwd -stdin $i
```

should be:

```
echo "$i:AIST2330password" | chpasswd
```

because the `--stdin` option to `passwd` has been deprecated.

Comment: How about some input sanitization? `for i in $(grep -Eo '^\w+' users.txt)` ?

Comment: Seems superfluous to me. The file should just be a simple one-name-per-line text file.